# ASP.NET Membership Send username across different tiers

Tags: asp.net, n-tier-architecture, custom-membershipprovider

I have 3-tiers (UI, BLL, DAL), those BLL and DAL reside on external WS, obviously my membership user works on the UI tier.

So... I was trying to store in my Bussines tables the username for the differents tasks (like a CRUD)

- Insert registry (username: nicolas)
- Delete registry (username: peter)
  etc...

The simplest way is send the username on ALL methods and store in the differents tables. But this idea is not scalable and very dirty if you have a lot of bussines tables.

Any know another way to do this? I read about writing a custom membership provider to store the differents user on cache and retrieve from this. But i don't know if this is the best workaround.

Any ideas?

Comment: The user is always available via the HttpContext

Comment: @Capar, good point. I personally do not like this as I prefer my BLL/DLL to not be dependent on a specific front end. That would pose problems if you wanted to extend an API off of your existing fuctionality.

Comment: Why do you say your MembershipUser works in the UI tier? I would think the Membership library is part of the BLL, and the particular implementation of MembershipProvider, such as SqlMembershipProvider, is part of the DAL.

Comment: Sorry my explanation about my tiers is wrong.
I have 3 tiers yeah, but the slighty difference radicate on the BLL, and DAL, those 2 tiers are in a WS.
So, the HttpContext only apply over the UI.

Comment: @Charlie Kilian, I don't have BLL and DAL for Membership. Only use the custom controls for asp.net. Do you recommend me use that approach to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom controls for ASP.NET rely on the Membership library in System.Web (more specifically, System.Web.Security). As long as you are using those controls (for example, the `<asp:Login>` control) you already have a dependency on System.Web. In that case, any layer of your application can do something like this to retrieve the current user:

```
using System.Web.Security;
...
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
```

Then use `user.UserName` to retrieve the user's username.

---

UPDATED to reflect the understanding that the layers are hosted on separate servers.

I would add a StartSession() method to the BLL that takes the username as a parameter, and returns a string session ID. The BLL on the server generates the session ID (perhaps using a Guid) and uses the BLL-side cache to save the username. Then on the client side, set a cookie that contains the session ID. It will get submitted along with the web request. (Depending on how you submit the web request, you may have to set the cookie value with javascript.)

That way you don't have to modify the signature of your methods, but can still get ahold of the username from the BLL by using the cache. You will have to make sure your login page calls the GetSession() method, and sets the session cookie before submitting more requests.

Comment: yep i know that. And of course it works perfectly on differents tiers on same context. But I have my DAL and BLL on different server. Is any chance to share my httpcontext or user between layers?

Comment: I would make the username a parameter to every call to the BLL/DAL. Or is this what you are trying to avoid?

Comment: If you are trying to avoid that, then you could add a StartSession() method to your BLL that the UI calls. It would take a username parameter, and return a session ID. Then set the session ID as a cookie. When you call the web service, the cookie would be sent with the call, allowing the server to look up the session. I am assuming you are using web services and that your front end is web-based. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes I trying to avoid that. And yes, is that correct. 
My architecture is Web UI (Server1) + WS (Server2) (BLL and DAL)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using services in the BLL and DLL then what is the point, there is no access to these except through the UI.

Comment: Yep, its true, I was edited my original post. Im using a service in BLL and DLL.